# onLoad function to onClick only

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

This code causes a particle explosion on my page.

I attached the onClick function to a button in my HTML so it runs when I click that certain button. But when I load the HTML it automatically runs this function and after that only when I click the button.

What I need is that it wont rune when you run the HTML. The function may only run when the button is clicked.

I also would like to ask how I can change te canvas size. Since this function automatically creates a canvas where the function loads in but this one is bigger than the div with the sizes I want it to run in.

```
//////////////settings/////////

var movementSpeed = 30;
var totalObjects = 500;
var objectSize = 70;
var sizeRandomness = 0;
var color = 0x00BEE0;


/////////////////////////////////
var dirs = [];
var parts = [];
//var container = document.createElement('div');
//document.body.appendChild( container );
var container = document.getElementById('header');
//document.body.appendChild( header );

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000)
camera.position.z = 1000;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

function ExplodeAnimation(x, y) {
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  for (i = 0; i < totalObjects; i++) {
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex.x = x;
    vertex.y = y;
    vertex.z = 0;

    geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
    dirs.push({
      x: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2),
      y: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2),
      z: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2)
    });
  }
  var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
    size: objectSize,
    color: color
  });
  var particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem(geometry, material);

  this.object = particles;
  this.status = true;

  this.xDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);
  this.yDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);
  this.zDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);

  scene.add(this.object);

  this.update = function() {
    if (this.status == true) {
      var pCount = totalObjects;
      while (pCount--) {
        var particle = this.object.geometry.vertices[pCount]
        particle.y += dirs[pCount].y;
        particle.x += dirs[pCount].x;
        particle.z += dirs[pCount].z;
      }
      this.object.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    }
  }

}

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
parts.push(new ExplodeAnimation(0, 0));
render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  var pCount = parts.length;
  while (pCount--) {
    parts[pCount].update();
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

window.addEventListener('mousedown', onclick, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

function onClick() {
  event.preventDefault();
  parts.push(new ExplodeAnimation((Math.random() * sizeRandomness) - (sizeRandomness / 2), (Math.random() * sizeRandomness) - (sizeRandomness / 2)));
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

Comment: Share a working snippet with the actual problem!

Comment: https://codepen.io/Xanmia/pen/DoljI?q=particle+explosion&limit=all&type=type-pens it is basically the same as this one. But i want to change the code so it only works when clicking on a certain button instead of immediatly when the page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I saw you code , I think you should only put your bellow  trigger code inside the click button :

```
renderer.render(scene, camera);
parts.push(new ExplodeAnimation(0, 0));
render();
```

because it's executed automatically when loading .

See My below Snippet , I ve added a sample button and run() function to show animation on click :

```js
//////////////settings/////////

var movementSpeed = 30;
var totalObjects = 500;
var objectSize = 70;
var sizeRandomness = 0;
var color = 0x00BEE0;


/////////////////////////////////
var dirs = [];
var parts = [];
//var container = document.createElement('div');
//document.body.appendChild( container );
var container = document.getElementById('header');
//document.body.appendChild( header );

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000)
camera.position.z = 1000;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

function ExplodeAnimation(x, y) {
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  for (i = 0; i < totalObjects; i++) {
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex.x = x;
    vertex.y = y;
    vertex.z = 0;

    geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
    dirs.push({
      x: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2),
      y: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2),
      z: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2)
    });
  }
  var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
    size: objectSize,
    color: color
  });
  var particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem(geometry, material);

  this.object = particles;
  this.status = true;

  this.xDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);
  this.yDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);
  this.zDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);

  scene.add(this.object);

  this.update = function() {
    if (this.status == true) {
      var pCount = totalObjects;
      while (pCount--) {
        var particle = this.object.geometry.vertices[pCount]
        particle.y += dirs[pCount].y;
        particle.x += dirs[pCount].x;
        particle.z += dirs[pCount].z;
      }
      this.object.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    }
  }

}

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();




function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  var pCount = parts.length;
  while (pCount--) {
    parts[pCount].update();
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

window.addEventListener('mousedown', onclick, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

function onClick() {
  event.preventDefault();
  parts.push(new ExplodeAnimation((Math.random() * sizeRandomness) - (sizeRandomness / 2), (Math.random() * sizeRandomness) - (sizeRandomness / 2)));
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click',run);

function run() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    parts.push(new ExplodeAnimation(0, 0));
    render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Click to run </button>
<div id="header">
```

Comment: Thanks man! This worked. Do you have any idea how I can set the window size to a custom size?

Comment: you mean , resizing window Automaticly ?

Comment: I want the function to load into my header. But when I launch the function it creates a canvas in the header div that resizes the header div.

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you mean :) , could you explain more

Comment: @CamielDeHoogt It's better to create a new SO question.

Comment: @prisoner849 for some reason I cannot click the submit question button when I try to post another..

Comment: @bRIMOs  
This is an example. Check out the menubar on the bottom. I want it to run in the dark blue area without the header moving down. youtu.be/ViwI_2bQ40A